# Changing base view type on MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-4, radix

I've read a post about changing base view type on MVC from the link below:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx

I followed the instructions but my page still inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`. I can't reach any property defined in my custom view base and I get an error on runtime. When I use `@inherits` keyword, it fixes.

**Web.config**

```
<pages pageBaseType="[MyNamespace].WebViewPageBase">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

**WebViewPageBase**

```
public class WebViewPageBase : WebViewPage
{
    public SomeType MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        MyProperty = { foo };
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {

    }
}


public class WebViewPageBase<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public SomeType MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        MyProperty = { foo };
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {

    }
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model TopMenuModel

<div class="topMenu">
@MyProperty
</div>
```

But in the post I've read there is no instruction about `@inherits` keyword. Is there any thing that I miss or any way to make this work without `@inherits` keyword in all pages?

**SOLVED:**

`web.config` file in `root` directory is not the right one. I changed base type in the `web.config` file under `View` directory and it fixed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Why did you show two versions of `WebViewPageBase`: generic and non-generic?

You only need the generic version:

```
public class MyWebView<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public SomeType MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        MyProperty = new SomeType();
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<pages pageBaseType="MvcApplication1.WebViews.MyWebView">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Now inside your views you will be able to use the property:

```
@model TopMenuModel

<div class="topMenu">
    @MyProperty
</div>
```

---

UPDATE:

Step by step setup:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the Internet Template
2. Add a custom base view:

   ```
   namespace MvcApplication1
   {
       public class MyWebView<T> : WebViewPage<T>
       {
           public string MyProperty { get; set; }

           public override void InitHelpers()
           {
               base.InitHelpers();
               MyProperty = "Hello World";
           }

           public override void Execute()
           {
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set the `pageBaseType` attribute in `~/Views/web.config` (not to be confused with `~/web.config`):

   ```
   <pages pageBaseType="MvcApplication1.MyWebView">
     <namespaces>
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
     </namespaces>
   </pages>
   ```
4. Inside `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` use the property:

   ```
   <div>
       @MyProperty
   </div>
   ```
5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> to run the application and if everything goes well you will be greeted with a `Hello World`.

Comment: I've just tried that. But same. I get an error says MyProperty doesn't exist in the context. And view class still inhertis from default: System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

Comment: That's weird. I cannot reproduce the problem. Let me update my answer with a step by step explanation.

Comment: The third step is exactly what I miss. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Why don't you need to implement the overrided methods?

Comment: That empty `Execute` is annoying.  I get it's an abstract in one of the base classes but has a name that implies is should not be executing nothing!

Comment: To avoid the need for an empty `Execute` method, just declare your custom WebViewPage class as `abstract`. There's no need for it to be a concrete type - the default type you're inheriting from is also abstract.

Comment: If anyone else is beating their head against the wall like me with this simple issue - close and reopen your solution.  Visual Studio 2017 was caching the old pageBaseType.  Once I closed and re-opened it worked.

Comment: Note: In case you get an error from ReSharper in your web.config, [simple create an additional non generic version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24956990/2441442).

Answer (score 6):

The problem you're having is because you need to modify the VIEWS folder's web.config file. So basically this line:

```
 <pages pageBaseType="[MyNamespace].WebViewPageBase">
```

needs to be in the web.config from your views folder not the main project's web.config. Darin Dimitrov's answer clearly specifies that, but people usually overlook that detail. I know because I was one of them. Actually so does Phil Haack's article...