# How to show/hide link inside navbar based on database settings using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a website where there are few administrators that can change which links that should be visible and accessible to the public. So the administrators should be able to save settings to the database, which later effect the link in the navbar depending if you are logged in or not.

I've added the possibility to save the settings, but I am not sure how to access them.

I've have stumbled upon `User.IsInRole("Administrator")` and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. But I do not think this will work since the visible links could change depending on whats saved in the database.

So how can I possibly solve this? Is there something built in MVC that could help me with this? Can I solve this without making requests to the database everytime the page loads?

If something is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that in your Model entity as their property particularly in your user then from there you can create a condition if the link will be shown our not:

```
@model Model.ModelUserEntity

if (@Model.IsAllowedToSeeLink) {
   //Show the link
}
```

So your ModelUserEntity has this property, so that you can flag if they have accessible links or not.

Comment: Ohh okey. But for this to work, I am needed to return the user model for every page I visit? Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Yes, you really need to return the Model, unless you want a static site, that you will only return pure View without your Model. Model keeps your View strongly type which you will need not just in this scenario but also in other aspect like validation.

Comment: Okey, thanks! Think I'll use your solution with a override on the base controller. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672627/7713556 - since I am already getting other models on different pages.